# XML cardView is blocking the top half of the recyclerView below it

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am new to android studio and XML I have a cardview that is blocking my recyclerview. At first I thought it was not working ,but once I took the card view out I could see the recycler.

What i need help on is so that my recylcer view start right below my cardview not matter how long the cardview gets.

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeReplies"
    android:background="#FF9D9D">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilePic"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="userName"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilePic"
                android:text="test" />



        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="601dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use is to create xml file separately for your views and then this file put into your main XML file which is registered with activity.

**1)** Create Xml file and put your cardView and recyclerview design in it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/HomeReplies">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilePic"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="userName"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilePic"
            android:text="test" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** make sure in above xml file you have added this two lines
**app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/HomeReplies"** in your parent layout.

**2)** Add above layout file into your **main XML** file using **include** tag.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF9D9D"
    tools:context=".HomeReplies">

       <include layout="@layout/content" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```